# iOS: Custom viewcontrollers as ivars

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

If I use a UICollectionView subclass **within another UIViewController** like so...

```
BrowseCVC *cvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BrowseItemVC"];
[self.containerScrollView addSubview:cvc.view];
```

... and either scroll the collection view or tap a cell, it will crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

However if I declare it as a `@property (strong, nonatomic) BrowseCVC *cvc;`) and use it like this...

```
self.cvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BrowseItemVC"];
[self.containerScrollView addSubview:self.cvc.view];
```

... everything works.

`BorwseCVC` is an unremarkable UICollectionViewController subclass with a very simple structure.

**My question is: Why?**

Comment: if i could write comments below 15 characters, i would just comment - ARC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARC takes care of memory management, but in these lines

```
BrowseCVC *cvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BrowseItemVC"];
[self.containerScrollView addSubview:cvc.view];
```

there's nothing to suggest to it that it should retain cvc. You only retain its view. cvc gets dealloced and you get exc_bad_access

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, `BrowseCVC` gets deallocated by ARC. You can work around this by either creating an iVar or property for it, or by adding it as a childViewController to your viewController:

```
BrowseCVC *cvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BrowseItemVC"];
[self addChildViewController:cvc];
[self.containerScrollView addSubview:cvc.view];
```

This should actually be the cleanest solution.